# PhoneGap/Cordova + Typescript= Error on FileWriter.onwrite method

Tags: cordova, typescript

I'm using typescript to write a mobile app with PhoneGap/Cordova and I'm facing an strange typesafe error with the FileWriter.onwrite method. See code below:

```
    fileEntry.createWriter(
        (writer: FileWriter) => 
        {
            writer.onwrite((event: ProgressEvent) => //Error here
            {
                console.log('success');
            });
        });
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
Error   8   Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target:
        Type '(event: ProgressEvent) => void' is missing property 'loaded' from type 'ProgressEvent'.
```

I tried changing the type of the 'event' param to any but it alse didn't work.

Is it something wrong with the lib.d.ts file? Or is there a different way to do it.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an assignment :

```
fileEntry.createWriter(
    (writer: FileWriter) => {
        writer.onwrite = (event: ProgressEvent) => // notice `=` not `()`
        {
            console.log('success');
        };
    });
```